# display external/linked image in XPage on Notes client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

I'm trying to display an image referenced by a url. I either set url property of the image to particular url (e.g. http://www.ibm.com/i/v16/t/ibm-logo.gif) or use computed text to display HTML img tag. In both cases image is visible in browser, but not on Notes client.

In fact the image seems to be there - once I set this property dynamically, the table cell containing the image, resizes to the size of it. But it is not visible.

I suspect this might be linked to some Notes client settings - to display or not display external images and not really related XPages. Could there anything I could set on client/database to allow displaying images? Once I receive an email with images, there is an option to enable images on page. Could this be the solution - to check in the mail db design to see how it is implemented(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPiNC (XPages in Notes Client) uses XULRunner (=embedded Firefox, unfortunately not the latest version) to render its content. It is rather restrictive in what it shows. There are some [goatchas around ports](http://xpages.info/XPagesHome.nsf/Entry.xsp?documentId=C7A2674F67E86D51852578CB00669AE6), but that doesn't seem your problem here. You might need to investigate proxy settings. If everything fails, you could use a backend class to download the image and use the binary data (no need to save to disk) as image source.

Comment: thanks Stephan, I could not get to the bottom of it, but downloading and attaching the images instead seemed to be a good solution also from other considerations

Comment: Did you download them to a file or use the "inline" method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme ?

Comment: I download as a file, attached and computed the link. reasonably straightforward and safer than rely on some images on internet out of my control. Well, on client now they are fine, but some of them are not showing up on server - a routine investigation :-) Inline sounds clever, but having them as a file - they can be easier re-used for other purposes.

Comment: well as it turns out java.net.URLEncoder encodes spaces as "+", so I still had to replace those manually... now it's tip-top